# jQuery: Add and Remove images

Tags: jquery, image, addition

I am new to jQuery.
I have 2 panels: If i click on an image in the left panel, then this image will appear in the right panel. I do it with clone(), so far i am here. Now i would like to have the image in the right panel be removed, when i click on it. And the count of summary weight (from img id) will depend on if i add or remove the images from the right panel. Can someone please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#output, #selectList { 
      width: 202px; 
      border: 1px solid #000; 
      margin: 2px; 
      height: 400px; 
      float: left 
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

summary weight: <div id="sumcount"></div>kg<br />
<div id="selectList">
    <img id="34" src="http://placekitten.com/80/80" />
    <img id="21" src="http://placekitten.com/81/81" />
    <img id="11" src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80" />
    <img id="5" src="http://placekitten.com/g/81/81" />
    <img id="9" src="http://placekitten.com/g/82/82" />
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var output = $('#output');
    //$('#selectList img').each(function(i, el){
    //        $(this).addClass('img' + i);
    //    });
    $('#selectList img').click(function(){
        output.append($(this).clone());
    });
    // dont work
    $('#output img').click(function(){
        output.remove($(this));
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XLSmU/

Comment: Removing can be done easily, check here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/XLSmU/1/ . I am not sure how do you want to count the weight.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/XLSmU/13/ . If weight is just adding/subtracting he value in ID.

Comment: Joy, it work. Thank you very much for the very quick help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var output = $('#output'),
        sumWeight = 0;

    $('#selectlist img').click(function() {
        var imageClone = $(this).clone();
        output.append(imageClone);
        sumWeight += parseInt( this.id, 10); // getting weight from image id
        $('#sumcount').text(sumWeight); /// updating the total weight
    });

    // for removing image from #output
    // you need delegate event, because images are added dynamically

    output.on('click', 'img', function() {
        var image = $(this),
            weight = parseInt( this.id, 10 ); // getting id of remove image
        sumWeight -= weight; // subtract weight from total
        image.remove();  // remove the image
        $('#sumcount').text(sumWeight); // updating the total weight
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XLSmU/16/)**

Comment: thecodeparadox, it work. Thank you very much for the very quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.clone()`, just pass the element itself - `$(this)`. So you end up with `output.append($(this));`, and that instead of cloning the element to the right list, will move it. That's how `.append` and the methods like it work.

About the weight counting:

1. Don't use `id` attributes for just numbers. That's not their intention, and a valid HTML element `id` contains at least one character. Instead, use a `data-id` attribute, and use it with `.data()`.
2. To count the amount of "weight" in the list, you can use `.each` to iterate on it and sum the amount, like this:

   ```
   var weight = 0;
   $('#selectlist img').each(function(){
        weight += $(this).data("id");
   });
   ```
3. Then, you can make a function out of it and re-calculate the weight with every change in the lists.
4. You should also take into consideration, that after moving the element to the right list, it still has all the events attached to it. If you make the events more general and less relying on which list they are currently in, that's fine; but otherwise, you should use `.live("click", function(){...});` for your event binding instead, as the elements may have different events on them after moving to the next list.

I've set up an example at jsFiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/XLSmU/17/

Comment: Dvir Azulay, i understand now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @hihox123 yet you embraced the ugly looking 3 mins late solution ;) j/k, I'm glad you solved your problem!

Comment: I always use the id attr, but now i am sure i was wrong and i will make more mistakes without your help. All your help is very important for my learn process. Thank you again!